# Peak identification, optimization [R]

Tags: r, optimization

I have followed the tutorial seen here: https://rpubs.com/mengxu/peak_detection

An my final function looks like this:

```
  cyclic_peaks <- function(x, y, w, span) {
    require(zoo)
    n <- length(y)
    y.smooth <- loess(y ~ x, span=span)$fitted
    y.max <- rollapply(zoo(y.smooth), 2*w+1, max, align="center")
    delta <- y.max - y.smooth[-c(1:w, n+1-1:w)]
    i.max <- which(delta <= 0) + w
    return(x[i.max])
  }
```

My issue is that i have measurements with more than 500.000 rows, and the runtime of this identification script i 96s, but do you have some ideas for optimization.

I have bloodpressures where i want to calculate cyclic mean, and thereby i need the peak identification.

Kind Regards!

Comment: zoo has rollmax for this. It would be faster.  Also the zoo functions work on ordinary objects, not just on zoo objects so you don't have to convert to zoo.  align = "center" is the default so does not have to be specified.